# PrimeFaces how to cancel event listener on filterBy component

Tags: javascript, jsf-2, primefaces

I'm using PrimeFaces dataTable with filterBy on a column.  I also have a link that when clicked, empty out the underlying table.  Everything works fine until I filter on something.  If I then clear the underlying table, the table is still displayed from cache and it won't get update to an empty table until I change the filterBy value.  It seems the filterBy input component is still holding on to the event listener.  Here's my code snipet:

```
<h:form id="logFormId" prependId="false">
  <p:dataTable value="#{logger.logLines}" var="logMsg"
  id="loggerTable" dynamic="false" widgetVar="logTable">
    <f:facet name="header">
      <h:commandLink action="#{logger.clearList}">
    <f:ajax render="@form" execute="@form" />
  </h:commandLink>
    </f:facet>
    <p:column>
  <f:facet name="header">
    <h:outputText value="#{msgs.LoggerDate}" />
  </f:facet>
  <h:outputText value="#{logMsg.dateText}" />
</p:column>
<p:column sortBy="#{logMsg.source}" 
    filterBy="#{logMsg.source}" filterMatchMode="contains" >
  <f:facet name="header">
    <h:outputText value="#{msgs.LoggerSource}  " />
  </f:facet>
  <h:outputText value="#{logMsg.source}" />
</p:column>
  </p:dataTable>
</h:form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I know the answer but here are some things to try.  I assume this is primefaces 2.2.

1. I don't think the dynamic attribute is used anymore in **p:datatable**.
2. In your **f:ajax** element, try **render="loggerTable"** instead of **@form**.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  Unfortunately, the behavior is unchanged when I made the modifications.  I am using Primefaces 2.2.1.  Binh